# Procedure not returning to C correctly in asm?

Tags: c, assembly, return, calling-convention, cdecl

I have a simple findAverage procedure written in assembly language that I am trying to call from a C main program. I had it working for a while, but all of a sudden it gives me this error when the procedure hits `ret`:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0000001E in projOne.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access violation executing location 0x0000001E.v
```

I have looked on the internet for answers but I cant seem to find one. Here is my C file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void printGrades(float grades[]){
    //Print the grades
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        printf("Grade %d: %.2f\n", i, grades[i]);
    }
}


void  findAverage(float* grades, float* average, int count);
void  findVariance(float* grades, float* variance, float average, int count);



int main(void){
    float average = 0.0f;
    float variance = 0.0f;
    float grades[] = { 60.0f, 66.4f, 76.6f, 67.9f, 98.4f, 76.3f, 89.0f, 90.5f, 87.4f, 66.9f, 56.7f, 79.1f, 89.2f, 91.3f, 92.5f, 91.1f, 94.2f, 99.5f, 100.0f, 76.6f, 88.4f, 99.8f, 79.8f, 86.5f, 81.3f, 82.1f, 83.1f, 81.1f, 99.1f, 88.0f };
    int count = 30;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Running Program...\n");

    //print original grades
    printGrades(grades);

    //find the average by calling asm proc
    findAverage(&grades[30], &average, count);

    //print average
    printf("The average is: %.2f\n", average);

    findVariance(&grades[30], &variance, average, count);

    //print variance
    printf("The variance is: %.2f\n", variance);


    return 0;
}
```

And here is my .asm file:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.DATA

nbrElts DWORD ?
one     DWORD 1
average DWORD ?

.CODE
_findAverage PROC NEAR32
    ;parameter 1 = source
    ;parameter 2 = dest
    ;parameter 3 = size of source

            push    ebp                         ;stack setup
            mov     ebp, esp
            finit                               ;initialize FPU
            fldz                                ;get ready for adding
            mov     eax, REAL4 PTR [ebp +8]     ;source
            mov     ebx, REAL4 PTR [ebp +12]    ;dest
            mov     ecx,[ebp+16]                ;size of source
            mov     nbrElts, ecx                ;count

    sumALL: ;FIND THE AVERAGE
            fadd    REAL4 PTR [eax]             ;ST += source[eax]
            add     eax, 4                      ;next element in source
            loop    sumAll              

            fidiv   nbrElts                     ;ST / count             
            fstp    REAL4 PTR[ebx]              ;dest <- ST                         

            pop     eax                         ;restore registers
            pop     ebx
            pop     ecx
            pop     ebp
            ret

_findAverage    ENDP
END
```

How do I properly return control to the calling program so that it can execute the next statements?

I am very new to Assembly language, so I apologize if there are any unconventional/weird ways of doing things. Feel free to correct me on those as well.

Comment: Compile and disassemble a test function to see the sequence at the beginning and end of function. Why you do `pop eax; pop ebx` - who has pushed them?

Comment: Yeah.. you call/retrun convention is all messed up.  The last thing you pushed was ebp, so you MUST pop it first.  The next thing on the stack is the return address, and popping it into a GP register is not effective.  In the case of 'callee removes parameters', there is a 'ret X' instruction.  Step through with your debugger and keep a note of esp :(

Comment: Okay I see now, out of desperation I was trying to fix it and I added pop eax, pop ebx... etc. I did not know that you had to push/pop in order, though I guess I should have known because that's how a stack works. Thanks yall.

Comment: It is not that the pushes and pops must be in the same order (though that almost always makes sense...) It's that they must be *balanced*. If you push two things, you pop two things. This is why understanding the calling convention really matters. Under some, the callee is responsible for unwinding the stack, in others the called function must unwind.